# How to make a TnT explode as soon as I place it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make my TnT explode as soon as I place it. how do I do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: As you want it to explode as soon as you place it, would it be fine if something other than TNT was used?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this I gonna be tough, but it here goes:
1. Name a mooshroom spawn egg "InstantTnt" or whatever else you want; just be sure to replace all the times I say "InstantTnt" with your name (as long as the new name doesn't have any spaces). I know this sounds weird, but it will all work in the end.
2. Type 
`/scoreboard objectives add isInstant dummy`
3. Put this on a clock (repeating command block): 
`/execute @e[name=InstantTnt] ~ ~ ~ /summon PrimedTnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:1}` 
4. Put this in a repeating command block as well: 
`/tp @e[name=InstantTnt] ~ -600 ~`
Done! Now, this will only work if you right click with a mooshroom spawner named "InstantTnt" (or whatever name you chose). To do this with a regular TNT block would be incredibly complex. 
One bug you may find is steak and leather appearing at the explosion. Tell me if this happens; I'll have to tweak the spawn egg to do so. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
/summon PrimedTnt ~ ~1 ~ {Fuse:80}
```

The name for activated TnT is *PrimedTnt*, The fuse timer is in Ticks (80 ticks = 4 sec)

Answer (score 0):

You first must place it on a device that will activate it immedientaly, like placing it on a redstone block, a light redstone torch, or even next to a flipped lever. Then it will explode automcaticaly.